# Regex: Avoid capturing spaces and quotes before and after matching word

Tags: python, regex

I'm trying to capture word IT, but only when it's a separate word and not inside text. But it also captures spaces and quotes that i don't need. I tried several variants with ^\s and ^\S but can't get things working right

[^\w]IT[^\w] - i was starting with this

Text where i'm searching is something like:

```
capture: industry: IT 
capture: ${Txt_new}         IT 
capture: ${Industry}    Set '${Original}'=='Banking'    IT  Banking 
capture: 'industry' : 'IT', 
capture: 'industry':"IT", 
skip   : ${Txt_IT}          word
skip   : ITinthemiddleITofwordIT
```

[My_Pattern.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3eoED.png)

Comment: Instead of posting pictures of text, you should post the actual text

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a word-boundary assertion: `\b`

```regex
/\bIT\b/g
```

Comment: Thanks, as usual resolution is simple and perfect, i spent couple hours looking at wrong things =)